# Prevent WordPress from messing my HTML

Tags: html, editor, wysiwyg, html-editor

Is there a way to prevent WP from modifying my perfectly fine HTML? When writing content of a page, I'm writing a list as

```
<ol>
  <li>Paragraph 1 : text

  Some more text</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ol>
```

then WP transform the HTML into

```
<ol>
  <li>Paragraph 1 : textSome more text</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ol>
```

This is coming frustrating as some of the lists are long and contain a few of these HTML configurations.

I tried wrapping the paragraphs inside `P` tags, but they too get removed and scrapped.

#### Update

The only solution I've found is [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-multi-paragraph-list-items) but it's rather hacky... I wish WP would not be such a pain about doing things I don't want nor ask for...

Comment: TinyMCE Advanced ( the chosen editor WordPress uses ) is pretty finicky when it comes nested elements. A better solution may be to use shortcodes but I'm not sure your specific usecase.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the text editor...

The example with the blank line in your question would normally be converted by WP to this:

```
<ol>
<li>Paragraph 1 : text
<p>  Some more text</p></li>
<li>…</li>
</ol>
```

Wpautop wraps the 2nd line with the p element because of the blank line you created.  Your example of WP's output would indicate wpautop has been disabled (by you or by a plugin).

With wpautop enabled it is pretty easy to add some CSS to create the space you want:

```
ol li p {
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

It might be better to add a class to your ol so the CSS rule only applies where you explicitly name it:

```
<ol class="my-ol-par">
    <li>Paragraph 1 : text
        <p>  Some more text</p></li>
    <li>…</li>
</ol>
```

With the CSS:

```
ol.my-ol-par li p {
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

If wpautop is disabled, and you don't want to enable it, you could always hard code your additional lines within the p element and use the same CSS solution.

UPDATE:

```
<ol>
    <li>Paragraph 1 : text

        Paragraph 2 : text

        Paragraph 3 : text</li>
    <li>…</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that, WP removes all `P` elements within the `LI` element. Even if I had set a CSS class to these paragraphs, the element would be removed altogether anyway. The "hacky" solution is to wrap everything inside my `LI` element with a `DIV`. Then, WP does not mess with the HTML. The point is that `wpautop` is removing HTML elements and this is just wrong.

Comment: The point I'm making is that the behavior you describe is not normal WP behavior, unless you are using the visual editor and/or wpautop is disabled.  As I mentioned, use the text editor NOT the visual editor.  When using the text editor with wpautop enabled the first '<li>" in your example should not appear as one line in the output.

Comment: What WP role are you logged in with?  By default the author role does not have the unfiltered_html capability.  You need the editor role or admin.

Comment: So, the answer to this is : "no, you cannot prevent WP from messing with the HTML". Or, to do so, I must wrap some elements or use CSS and different HTML tags.

Comment: No, the answer is WP should not be doing that to your code IF you create and save it with the Text Editor.  Creating a post with HTML in the Visual Editor and OR later opening and saving it with the Visual Editor **will change** the HTML.  I tested this with a fresh WP install using 2016 theme.  Using the text editor, I posted the code shown at the end of my answer under UPDATE. You can see the resulting WP output here: http://so.bkstest.com/